# I am getting an error ReportPage line 4, column 2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

```
<apex:page>
<h1>Record details1</h1>
<h1>Record details2</h1>
<h1>Record details3</h1>
</apex:page>
<apex:component controller="ReportExportController" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="reportId" description="Id of the report to be retrieved." type="Id" assignTo="{!reportId}" />
    <apex:attribute name="format" description="'printable', 'csv','xls'" type="String" assignTo="{!format}"/>
    <apex:attribute name="prettify" description="Select if you want to try cutting out headers and footers." type="Boolean" default="true" assignTo="{!prettify}"/>
    <apex:attribute name="encoding" description="Text encoding (UTF-8 etc)." type="String" default="UTF-8" assignTo="{!encoding}" />
    <apex:attribute name="showDetails" description="If 'printable' is used - choose if you want to override report's show/hide details setting. Use 'yes' or 'no'" 
        type="String" assignTo="{!showDetails}" />
    <apex:outputText value="{!output}" escape="false" />
</apex:component>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message - you can't declare the `<apex:component>` and the `<apex:page>` in the same file. The component needs to be separate.

Update: As @javanoob commented, an apex:page needs to be created in a Visualforce page file, and an apex:component should be created in a Visualforce component file. They have different extensions.

Comment: if i remove apex:page then it showing error, <apex:page> is required and must be the outermost tag in the markup at line 1 column 1

Comment: To create apex component, you should select Apex component as the metadata type. Not sure what IDE you are using but try to create new Visualforce component and in that just give apex:component tags.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a visualforce component as:

```
<apex:component controller="ReportExportController" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="reportId" description="Id of the report to be retrieved." type="Id" assignTo="{!reportId}" />
    <apex:attribute name="format" description="'printable', 'csv','xls'" type="String" assignTo="{!format}"/>
    <apex:attribute name="prettify" description="Select if you want to try cutting out headers and footers." type="Boolean" default="true" assignTo="{!prettify}"/>
    <apex:attribute name="encoding" description="Text encoding (UTF-8 etc)." type="String" default="UTF-8" assignTo="{!encoding}" />
    <apex:attribute name="showDetails" description="If 'printable' is used - choose if you want to override report's show/hide details setting. Use 'yes' or 'no'" 
        type="String" assignTo="{!showDetails}" />
    <apex:outputText value="{!output}" escape="false" />
</apex:component>
```

then you can use the component in the visualforce page as:

```
<apex:page>
<h1>Record details1</h1>
<h1>Record details2</h1>
<h1>Record details3</h1>
<c:componentName    reportId="{!someId}"
                    format="{!someFormat}"
                    prettify="{!someprettify}"
                    showDetails="{!somedetails}"
                    encoding="{!someEncoding}"/>
</apex:page>
```